# twilio dial numbers in sequence

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I'd like to have a user make a series of calls in sequence (not simultaneously). The preferred interaction would be:

```
<say>Connecting now. Press # to continue to the next call</say>
[dials a number]
[gathers # keypress and dials next number]
...
<say>Thanks</say>
```

Is this possible? Or do I need to use the `dial action` parameter to call the user back with the next call when they hangup?

Answer (score 5):

Twilio evangelist here.

You should be able to use the hangupOnStar attribute to accomplish this:

```
<Response>
    <Say>Connecting now. Press star to continue to the next call</Say>
    <Dial hangupOnStar="true">+15555555555</Dial>
    <Dial hangupOnStar="true">+15555556666</Dial>
    <Dial hangupOnStar="true">+15555557777</Dial>
    <Say>Thanks</Say>
</Response>
```

This attribute lets the calling party disconnect from the called party by pressing the * key.  When that happens Twilio will move to and execute the next TwiML verb.

Hope that helps.